# How to escape all HTML entities in show_popup() method and fix Parse Error in Sublime Text 3 plugin?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am making a plugin for Sublime Text 3. It contacts my server in Java and receives a response in the form of a list of strings, that contains C code. 
To display this code in a popup window you need to pass a string in HTML format to the method show_popup. Accordingly, all C-code characters that can be recognized by the parser as HTML entities should be replaced with their names (&name;) or numbers (&#number;). At first, I just replaced the most common characters with replace(), but it didn't always work out - Parse Error was displayed in the console:

```
    Parse Error: <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;printf&nbsp;("Decimals:&nbsp;%d&nbsp;%ld\n",&nbsp;1977,&nbsp;650000L);
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;printf&nbsp;("Preceding&nbsp;with&nbsp;blanks:&nbs 

...

y</a></li><p><b>____________________________________________________</b></p>
                    </ul>
                </body>
             code: Unexpected character
```

I've tried to escape html entities with Python's html library:

```
import html
... 
html.escape(string)
```

But Sublime doesn't see import and print in console that I was using a function without defining it - I guess he didn't see that I connected this library(Whyyy?). cgi.escape - is depricated, so I can't use this. I decided to write the function myself.

Then I saw a very interesting way to replace all the characters whose code is >127 and some other characters (&, <,>) with their numbers:

```
def escape_html (s):
    out = ""
    i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        c = s[i]
        number = ord(c)
        if number > 127 or c == '"' or c == '\'' or c == '<' or c == '>' or c == '&':
            out += "&#"
            out += str(number)
            out += ";"
        else:
            out += c
        i += 1
    out = out.replace(" ", "&nbsp;")
    out = out.replace("\n", "<br>")
    return out
```

This code works perfectly for displaying characters in a browser, but unfortunately it is not supported by Sublime Text 3.

As a result, I came to the conclusion that these characters should be replaced with their equivalent names:

```
def dumb_escape_html(s):
    entities = [["&", "&amp;"], ["<", "&lt;"], [">", "&gt;"], ["\n", "<br>"],
                [" ", "&nbsp;"]]
    for entity in entities:
        s = s.replace(entity[0], entity[1])
    return s
```

But again I faced an obstacle: not all names are supported in Sublime. And again an error Parse Error.

I also attach a link to JSON file, which contains answer from my server, content of which should be displayed in pop-up window: [Example of data from sever (codeshare.io)](https://codeshare.io/5e6R6K)

I absolutely do not understand, in what I make a mistake - I hope, that great programmers know how to solve my problem.

Edit. Minimal, Reproducible Example:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

import string
import sys
import json


def get_func_name(line, column):
    return "printf"

def get_const_data(func_name):
    input_file = open ("PATH_TO_JSON/data_printf.json")
    results = json.load(input_file)
    return results

def dumb_escape_html(s):
    entities = [["&", "&amp;"], ["<", "&lt;"], [">", "&gt;"], ["\n", "<br>"],
                [" ", "&nbsp;"]]
    for entity in entities:
        s = s.replace(entity[0], entity[1])
    return s

def dumb_unescape_html(s):
    entities = [["&lt;", "<"], ["&gt;", ">"], ["<br>", "\n"],
                ["&nbsp;", " "], ["&amp;", "&"]]
    for entity in entities:
        s = s.replace(entity[0], entity[1])
    return s

class CoderecsysCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        v = self.view
        cur_line = v.substr(v.line(v.sel()[0]))
        for sel in v.sel():
            line_begin = v.rowcol(sel.begin())[0]
            line_end = v.rowcol(sel.end())[0]

        pos = v.rowcol(v.sel()[0].begin()) # (row, column)

        try:
            func_name = get_func_name(cur_line, pos[1]-1)
            li_tree = ""
            final_data = get_const_data(func_name)
            for i in range(len(final_data)):
                source = "source: " + final_data[i]["source"]
                escaped = dumb_escape_html(final_data[i]["code"])
                divider = "<b>____________________________________________________</b>"
                li_tree += "<li><p>%s</p>%s <a href='%s'>Copy</a></li><p>%s</p>" %(source, escaped, escaped, divider)
        # The html to be shown.
            html = """
                <body id=copy-multiline>
                    Examples of using <b>%s</b> function.
                    <ul>
                        %s
                    </ul>
                </body>
            """ %(func_name, li_tree)
            self.view.show_popup(html, max_width=700, on_navigate=lambda example: self.copy_example(example, func_name, source))
        except Exception as ex:
            self.view.show_popup("<b style=\"color:#1c87c9\">CodeRec Error:</b> " + str(ex), max_width=700)


    def copy_example(self, example, func_name, source):
        # Copies the code to the clipboard.
        unescaped = dumb_unescape_html(example)
        unescaped = "// " + source + unescaped
        sublime.set_clipboard(unescaped)
        self.view.hide_popup()
        sublime.status_message('Example of using ' + func_name + ' copied to clipboard !')
```

Comment: Please create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem you're having. As it is now, it's nearly impossible to follow along with what you're trying to do. Have you looked at the source of other Sublime plugins to see how they do this same thing?

Comment: Also, please keep in mind the `<code>` tag. Inject that into your HTML string being sent to `show_popup()` and you won't have to bother trying to escape every single character.

Comment: @MattDMo I added Minimal, Reproducible Example. About looking at the source of other Sublime plugins: I looked at the ones that showed a pop-up window, but they were just text, not code. Now I tried to add the <code> tag, but I did not notice the effect - still the same Parse Error.